# ItemsControl to display several layers of data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I’ve got an `ObservableCollection` of objects that are classified with a name and a set of 3D coordinates. I’ve also got an `ObservableCollection` of layers, each supposed to hold a 2D grid.

### Problem Setting

The objective is to use an `ItemsControl`, probably nested, to display those objects in the following fashion: if the Z coordinate determines the layer, and the X and Y coordinates specify each object’s position on the grid, then the object should be displayed in a `TabControl`, where the `TabItem` corresponds to the Z coordinate and hosts a `Grid` where the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` attributes determine where the object’s name is written on the `TabItem`.

Important: while each 3D coordinate is only used once, one “Entry” object may have multiple 3D coordinates, and as such may appear various times on a grid and/or different `TabItems`.

Note: the data model is not carved in stone; if the problem can be solved with another data model, I’m open to change it. The display, however, is a customer requirement—it might be modified, but I’d need extremely good arguments for that.

### Background Info

The objects look like this (`BindableBase` is from the Prism Library):

```
public class Entry : BindableBase {
  public string Name { set; get; }

  private EntryCoordinates coordinates;
  public EntryCoordinates Coordinates {
    set { SetProperty(ref coordinates, value); }
    get { return coordinates; }
  }
}

public class EntryCoordinates : BindableBase {
  private int x;
  public int X {
    set { SetProperty(ref x, value); }
    get { return x; }
  }

  private int y;
  public int Y {
    set { SetProperty(ref y, value); }
    get { return y; }
  }

  private int z;
  public int Z {
    set { SetProperty(ref z, value); }
    get { return z; }
  }
}
```

The `Entry` objects are hosted in “entry layers”:

```
public class EntryLayer : ObservableCollection<Entry> {
}
```

Eventually, I want to be able to modify the `Entry` objects (which are more complex in reality) via the UI, so two-way data binding is an absolute necessity.

### Effort so far

Using @Rachel’s excellent [WPF Grid Extension](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/), I implemented an `ItemsControl` that populates a `Grid` as desired:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EntryLayers, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <Grid GridExtension.RowCount="{Binding RowCount}"
            GridExtension.ColumnCount="{Binding ColumnCount}"
            GridExtension.StarRows="{Binding StarRows}"
            GridExtension.StarColumns="{Binding StarColumns}"
            IsItemsHost="True"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>

  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
      <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Coordinates.X}"/>
      <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Coordinates.Y}"/>
    </Style>
  </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <GridCellThumb XCoordinate="{Binding Coordinates.X}"
                     YCoordinate="{Binding Coordinates.Y}">
        <Thumb.Template>
          <ControlTemplate>
            <TileControl Entry="{Binding}"/>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Thumb.Template>
      </GridCellThumb>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The `GridCellThumb` is a custom control that allows for drag and drop (omitted here for clarity’s sake) and exposes coordinate dependency properties:

```
public class GridCellThumb : Thumb {
  public static readonly DependencyProperty XCoordinateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("XCoordinate", typeof(int), typeof(GridCellThumb));
  public int XCoordinate {
    get { return (int)GetValue(XCoordinateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(XCoordinateProperty, value); }
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty YCoordinateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("YCoordinate", typeof(int), typeof(GridCellThumb));
  public int YCoordinate {
    get { return (int)GetValue(YCoordinateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(YCoordinateProperty, value); }
  }
}
```

The `TileControl` is a user control that displays an `Entry`’s name:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
  <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I’m stuck in finding out how to wrap the original `ItemsControl` in a `TabControl` template so that the objective of displaying an entry, possible various times, correctly. For instance, binding to the `Coordinates.Z` path works, but creates as many `TabItems` as there are entries:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}">
  <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
      <Setter Property="Header"
              Value="{Binding Coordinates.Z}" />
      <Setter Property="TabIndex"
              Value="{Binding Coordinates.Z}" />
    </Style>
  </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
  <!-- the ItemsControl goes here -->
</TabControl>
```

I’ve tried the solutions proposed by @greg40 ([nested `ItemsControl`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44884043/3517056)), @d.moncada ([another nested `ItemsControl`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25085673/3517056)), and @Sheridan ([going up the visual tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29011669/3517056)), but I always gloriously fail when relating an `Entry` to a given `EntryLayer`.

Does anyone have further ideas to explore? As I said, I’m also open to re-structuring my data model, if that leads to an easier solution.

### Update 2018-01-08

I’ve explored the path of using `Button`s instead of a `TabControl` in the sense of data-binding their clicked state to displaying varying information on the grid. This, however, only shifted the problem and created a new one: the data isn’t pre-loaded anymore, which is crucial to the customer’s requirements.

I’m now strongly considering to suggest a change of requirements to the customer and devise a different data model altogether. In order to avoid taking a wrong route again, I’d very much appreciate if there was someone in the community with a strong opinion about this problem that they’d be willing to share with me.

Comment: Another thought: there’s a 1-to-many relationship between `Entry` and `Coordinate`. The `Coordinate` determines both the layer and the grid. Would it be more feasible to have the `ItemsControl` as the outer tag and the `TabControl` as the inner one? But how would one then render the `TabItem`s so that they contain their corresponding `Grid`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some very valuable offline advice from a peer expert, I decided against the customer suggested data model and provide them with an alternative solution. The approach is now to fill the *View* in a top-down fashion.

In essence, this means that what was previously my *Z* coordinate is now the index of a dedicated `EntryLayer` object defining the `TabItem`s. Each `EntryLayer` has an `ObservableCollection<Entry>` that refers to those `Entry`s that a parts of that `EntryLayer`.

This contrasts to the initial model in the sense that now it’s not possible anymore that a `Entry` can have multiple coordinates; instead, the `Entry` itself might exist multiple times with different coordinates.

How did I sell it to the customer? I told them that now an `Entry` could have customization options that may differ between its representations on the same or other `EntryLayer`s, e.g., by using user-specified colors and fonts, while still pointing back to the same base information. It gives me some more work to do implementation-wise, but it elegantly solves the deadlock by putting it in the shape of a new feature.